# Unable to connect to respo at URL when I upgrade one folder in my local repo？

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN ， when it remind me to upgrade one of the folder.
After that , I can't connect to the repo on this upgraded folder.
So, anybody to help?

Comment: when update on local repo : Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to  PROPFIND request for '/svn'

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you've done that started the issue (upgrade a working copy, upgrade the repository).  If you used the command line tools for any of these steps what commands did you run?  What action are you taking when you get the error about PROPFIND?